# dafny set membership implications

Tags: set, dafny

Verifying another simple problem [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/) for the following TypeScript code.

```
function containsDuplicate(nums: number[]): boolean {
    let m = new Set();
    for(let elem of nums) {
        if(m.has(elem)) {
            return true;
        }
        m.add(elem);
    }
    return false;
};
```

I run into situation where I can get the method to verify based on setSeq, but not on the variable windowSet.

```
function method seqSet(nums: seq<int>, index: nat): set<int> {
    set x | 0 <= x < index < |nums| :: nums[x]
}

method containsDuplicateI(nums: seq<int>) returns (containsDuplicate: bool)
    ensures containsDuplicate ==>  exists i,j :: 0 <= i < j < |nums| && nums[i] == nums[j]
{
    var windowGhost: set<int> := {};
    var windowSet: set<int> := {};
    for i:= 0 to |nums| 
        invariant 0 <= i <= |nums|
        invariant forall j :: 0 <= j < i < |nums|  ==> nums[j] in windowSet
        invariant forall x :: x in windowSet ==> x in nums
        invariant seqSet(nums, i) <= windowSet
    {
        windowGhost := windowSet;
        // if nums[i] in windowSet { // does not verify
        if nums[i] in seqSet(nums, i) { //verifies
            return true;
        }
        windowSet := windowSet + {nums[i]};
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems like because window set is updated that it cannot be equal to the result of seqSet, at least asserting so fails. How do I change the invariants such that I can verify the method using the membership test in the non-ghost variable rather than the function set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing `invariant forall x :: x in windowSet ==> x in nums` to `invariant forall x :: x in windowSet ==> x in nums[0..i]`, I am able to verify.